# Executing Vmware PowerShell Commands in Java Program

Tags: java, powershell, vmware

I wrote a Java program which executes a PowerShell Command. Here is my code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PowerShellCommand {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String command = "powershell.exe  your command";
    // Getting the version
    String command = "powershell.exe  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion";
    // Executing the command
    Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    // Getting the results
    powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
    String line;
    System.out.println("Standard Output:");
    BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    stdout.close();
    System.out.println("Standard Error:");
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    stderr.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

What I want to do is: instead of executing a command in a local PowerShell I want to make the code execute a command in the Windows Server PowerShell which is running on VMware? How should I modify the code to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Have PowerShell [invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Invoke-Command) the command on the remote host:

```java
String server  = "remotehost";
String command = "powershell.exe -Command \"&{Invoke-Command -Computer " +
                 server + " -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion}}\"";
```

The remote host needs to have [PSRemoting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2014/07/03/ps-remoting-considerations/) enabled for this to work.

Comment: I Did as u told me But this error pops up: Connecting to remote server 192.168.2.3 failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For 
more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (192.168.2.3:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken------------------------------------------------------------I did a lots of research but I couldn't find anything to handle this

Comment: Did you "see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic"?